# how to get list of mappings and workflows that are running on DIS in informatica developer

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

The problem statement is that I want to get the count of mappings and workflows (from all the applications that are running) on Data Integration Service (ps the tool is Informatica Developer, I am aware of how this can be done in Informatica powercenter).
We want to limit the number of jobs running on DIS at any particular time to 100.

For workflows, I found a command (infacmd.sh wfs listActiveWorkflowInstances) but there is nothing similar which gives me the same for mappings as well.

Other way is to query the metadata tables. For mappings, I tried querying the table mrx_mapping_serv_req but it only has an entry after the mapping gets completed. It does not show an entry when the mapping is running.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get "running mappings" - `Mappings` is a different concept. On IS there are only `Workflows` and `Sessions` running.
Having said that, it is possible to set the limit for number of concurrently executed session in `Administration Console`. Here's a quote from [KB](https://kb.informatica.com/howto/1/Pages/18667.aspx):

> Follow the steps mentioned below to configure the maximum number of
>   sessions:
>
> Log in to the Informatica Administration Console.
>
> Select the node on which the Integration Service is running.
>
> Click on the Node properties.
>
> Under Resource Provision Threshold change the value of the Maximum
>   Processes property to increase the number of sessions that can run
>   concurrently on this integration service.  The default value is 10.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this answer relates to Informatica Powercenter world. My question is for BDM environment where an application contains mapping or workflow. There are no sessions in Informatica developer.

Answer (score -1):

If your main goal is to limit the number of jobs running in the DIS, then you can do that by modifying the Execution Pool Size in the DIS.

1. Login to Admin Console
2. Click on Manage then Services and Nodes
3. Go to you Domain and click on your DIS
4. Under Execution Options, there should be options for Maximum On-Demand Execution Pool size, Maximum Native Execution Pool Size and Maximum Hadoop Execution Pool Size (if you have BDM). Modify them accordingly.